# jQuery Scroll To bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

After my page is done loading. I want jQUery to nicely scroll to the bottom of the page, animating quickly, not a snap/jolt.

Do iI need a plugin like `ScrollTo` for that? or is that built into jQuery some how?

Comment: The scripts mentioned in previous answers, like: $("body, html").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 400) **will not work** in *Chrome* and will be jumpy in *Safari* **in case** `html` tag in *CSS* has `overflow: auto;` property set. It took me nearly an hour to figure out.

Answer (score 482, accepted):

You can just animate to scroll down the page by animating the `scrollTop` property, no plugin required, like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
});
```

Note the use of `window.onload` (when images are loaded...which occupy height) rather than `document.ready`.

To be technically correct, you need to subtract the window's height, but the above works:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height() });
```

---

To scroll to a particular ID, use its [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/), like this:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#myID").scrollTop() }, 1000);
```

Comment: Can you controll the speed? And the #ID it goes to?

Comment: @AnApprentice - If you want to scroll to a particular ID it would look like `$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#myID").scrollTop() }, 1000);` for it take one second.

Comment: Another issue, is when it seems done, and then the user trys to scoll up, for a little bit it's locked, and makes a very jolting effect, preventing the user from scrolling up

Comment: If I get rid of the 1000 it doesn't do that.

Comment: @AnApprentice - That's because it happens quickly (400ms by default), I'd recommend just a quick scroll to alleviate that issue.

Comment: is there a way to put a stop() it the func so when it's done it doesn't get locked?

Comment: @AnApprentice - when it's done it'll unlock already, you can't just add a stop because this triggers the event that matters..`scroll`, you could bind to mouse wheel, but clicks on the scrollbar wouldn't register.

Comment: The lock is because the distance is off. It is animating past the visible animation.

Comment: for scrollable elements, the attribute `scrollHeight` is helpful.

Comment: @NickCraver - with latest version of jQuery .scrollTop() seems not working to scroll to a particular ID; with .offset().top should work:  `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#myID").offset().top }, 1000);`

Comment: This answer needs to be edited. `$(document).height()` is too great of a value for `scrollTop` property, you can notice that by the easing. I think `$(document).height() - window.innerHeight` should be ok.

Comment: note that in jQuery 3.0, you have to use `$(window).on("load", function() {` instead of `$(window).load(function() {`

Comment: What do you mean "technically correct". Do you mean "correct", because that's what the second code block is. The top code block does not give the desired behavior.

Answer (score 27):

something like this:

```
var $target = $('html,body'); 
$target.animate({scrollTop: $target.height()}, 1000);
```

Comment: I tried updating the target to .write-comment and it didn't work. Maybe because that's being injected into the page?

Answer (score 22):

You can try this

```
var scroll=$('#scroll');
scroll.animate({scrollTop: scroll.prop("scrollHeight")});
```

Answer (score 19):

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 9999 }, 'slow');
```

As simple as this , 9999 page height ... big range so it can reach to bottom .

Comment: This is not perfect, as in some cases, even if rare, there might be pages longer than that, specially pages that load unlimited content dynamically. This will stop the scroll mid way.

Comment: @Gass It's been years since I wrote that, or have used any JS. Anyway, I checked and using either `Infinity` or too many 9s breaks the logic, at least in latest Chrome and FF, and instead scrolls to the top.

Answer (score 9):

```
$("div").scrollTop(1000);
```

Works for me. Scrolls to the bottom.

Comment: Not if your page is longer than 1000px.

Answer (score 5):

Using  'document.body.clientHeight' you can get the seen height of the body elements

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#particularDivision").offset().top - document.body.clientHeight + $("#particularDivision").height()
}, 1000);
```

this scrolls at the id 'particularDivision'

Answer (score 4):

```
function scrollToBottom() {
     $("#mContainer").animate({ scrollTop: $("#mContainer")[0].scrollHeight }, 1000);
}
```

This is the solution work from me and you find, I'm sure

Comment: It's bad practice to use the same selector twice like that as it's performing the dom selector query twice, unnecessarily hitting performance. It's better to assign the element collection to a const and reuse it like: const $container = $("#mContainer"); $container.animate({ scrollTop: $container[0].scrollHeight }, 1000);

Answer (score 2):

For jQuery 3, Please change

> $(window).load(function() {
>   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
>   })

to:

> $(window).on("load", function (e) {
>   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
>   })

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#pagedwn').bind("click", function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:3031 },"fast");
        return false;
});
```

*This solution worked for me.* It is working in Page Scroll Down fastly.

Answer (score 0):

js

```
var el = document.getElementById("el");
el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight - el.scrollTop;
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pixelFromTop = 500;     
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: pixelFromTop  }, 1);
```

So when page open it is automatically scroll down after 1 milisecond