# Jump to the bottom of the page with jQuery - Without animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I jump to the bottom of the page with jQuery?

I don't want a smoother animation, just to 'jump'. All the other questions on this site I found seem to involve an animation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Scroll To bottom of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249353/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: @JonathanNaguin it's not a duplicate really.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This will do

```
$('html, body').scrollTop( $(document).height() );
```

[**`scrollTop( vHeight );`**](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop)

Answer (score 11):

**WITH ANIMATION**

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
```

**WITHOUT ANIMATION**

```
$('html, body').scrollTop( $(document).height() );
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#smthn').scrollTop(99999999999);`

99999999999 is the max input for jquery and it can take element to the last scrolling position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anchor tag for this, no need of jquery.

Put an anchor tag at the bottom of the page just before `</body>` tag. such as

```
<a name="pageend"></a>
```

And, from where on the page you can jump to the bottom, put another anchor tag just like this.

```
<a href="#pageend">Jump to page end</a>
```