# How to go to bottom of the list in dataView of Sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a Dataview of list in Sharepoint 2013; and I want to go bottom of the Page on a button click or loading of page. Are there any ways to achieve the same??

I tried it with the jQueries, javascript and Hyperlink but the ShowInGrid=True get broken and Gridview in page disappears.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Ya I tried Using hyperlink like <a href="DivBottom">Go to bottom </a>..........<div id="DIvBottom"></div>   I have even used javascript scroll functions

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249353/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I have already tried that..and It gave me same error!! the ShowInGrid=True of url went missing

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue on JSFiddle or any other editor site?

Comment: Sir I have a List suppose 'abc' ;in that list i have a dataview, and I want to go to bottom of the that  gridview(i.e, bottom of the page) but if i use <a href=" "> the URL gets disturbed and the gridview disappears and javascript scroll function didn't help me!! Sorry I can't Reproduce the issue since it is in sharepoint webparts