# Loading bottom of page every time on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to load bottom of page every time when a page is loaded? Or to scroll down automatically?

If you have any suggestions it would be great.

Also this is for my chat app and I need to scroll down on every new message...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249353/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll to the bottom of your page:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Or, if you have an element you want to scroll to the bottom of:

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("your_div");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

jQuery:

```
$("#your_div").scrollTop($("#your_div")[0].scrollHeight);
```