# How can I scroll down the page so that a designated element is at the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have this jQuery that gets html data back from a Controller method, and adds it to an up-until-then-empty element:

```
$("#btnViewList").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GeneratePDFOfReportFutures", "GenerateScheduledRptsPDF")',
        success: function (retval) {
            $("#tableshell").append($(retval));
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error in btnViewList');
        }
    }); 
});
```

The element being inflated is simply:'

```
<div id="tableshell">   
</div>
```

After that data is appended, I want to scroll down the page so that the dynamically added html is visible without the user having to manually scroll down the page. I found code [jQuery Scroll To bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249353/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page]) to move to the *bottom* of the page, and it works, but I want the first part of the newly-added html to be visible at the top of the area visible after scrolling.

How is that accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this code

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#tableshell").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

pls let me know if this worked for you

Comment: Is there any advantage to doing it that way over the way I show below?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy as pie, using "plain old" Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("tableshell").scrollIntoView();
```

For whatever reason, the jQueryified version:

```
$("#tableshell").scrollIntoView();
```

...does not work.

So my jQuery is now:

```
$("#btnViewList").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GeneratePDFOfReportFutures", "GenerateScheduledRptsPDF")',
        success: function (retval) {
            $("#tableshell").append($(retval));
            document.getElementById("tableshell").scrollIntoView();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('great oogly moogly - Zappa missed Mother's day!');
        }
    });
});
```