# Why doesn’t $(window) work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, but not work in chrome

```
var win = $(window);
($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop())
```

I searched the Internet and found with the 'body' now works however are run at the top of the page, how do I run to get to the bottom of the page?

```
($(document).height()  - $('body').height() == $('body').scrollTop())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249353/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need call your functionality after document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var win = $(window);
    ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) 
})
```

Comment: yes, but i already have add document.ready but not work in chrome

Comment: what u try to do? I mean write task

Comment: I have done. what I wanted to do was check arrived at the bottom of the page, the error was due to the ratio of the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Get the document height using and scroll to the bottom using .scrollTop();

```
 var height=$(document).height();
 $('body').scrollTop(height)
```