# Bootstrap 4 - what is the speed of collapsing animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How fast is the Bootstrap 4 [collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) animation? I am unable to find it in the messy `bootstrap.js` file. 
My goal is to scroll down to the bottom of unpacked div with the same speed as the default Bootstrap collapsing. I use a code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4249353/3764965).

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#myID").scrollTop()}, 1000);
```

I want to find a precise value instead of `1000` which is too small causing the scrolling is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the jQuery documentation on **[`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)**:

> Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The default duration is `400` milliseconds. The strings `'fast'` and `'slow'` can be supplied to indicate durations of `200` and `600` milliseconds, respectively.

The value you are looking for should be `400`.

Comment: A piece of cake for you! It matches the Bootstrap collapsing well. So Bootstap uses the default animation speed? Is it this fact documented anywhere on the Bootstrap side?