# How to scroll to the bottom of the page in a mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to scroll down to the bottom of the page when a new message is received or sent, I have everything set up and it's working fine on my laptop but when I try accessing my website on a mobile device the scroll event is not working.

Well I have used both of jQuery scroll, and pure javascript scroll but none of them worked on the mobile device

Here are all the functions that I used which I found all across the internet:

```
//first method
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);

//second method
$("html,body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
}, "slow");

//third method
$('my-messages-container').animate({ scrollTop : $(document).height()+1000000 });
```

well, the code is working fine when I use the developer tools mobile simulation. but when I try it on a real mobile device it doesn't work.

Comment: $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(); ?

Comment: i just tried that , still no luck.

Comment: How exactly are you calling these methods ?

Comment: When the user clicks on the send button , a function is called do some stuff and then comes one of these methods

Answer (score 2):

```
elementAtBottomOfPage.scrollIntoView()
```

Is what finally ended up working for me, on iOS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Answer (score -1):

As stated on: [jQuery Scroll To bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249353/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page)

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height()});
```

Would get you to the bottom of the page.

Comment: i know and it works fine on a web browser but on a mobile device it dosen't.