# Scroll Position to last in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**How can I scroll my div with class main to last scroll position**

**means the scroll bar goes automatically at the end**

Comment: Please can anyone help me 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Scroll To bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249353/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: Let me check Wait a minute.

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: Instead of begging for help, how about you post a [mre] showing what you've tried to far, and any error messages you got? This isn't a free code writing service.

Comment: Bro I am trying to do it from a hour 

Comment: Here, took five minutes: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/94rqk2en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try with scrollTop

```
document.querySelector('.main').scrollTop = document.querySelector('.main').scrollHeight
```

so you change the height by top position of the scroll

Comment: document.querySelector('.main').scrollTop = document.querySelector('.main').scrollHeight

Comment: Should it go like this for me when I have a div with .main

Comment: Hi please help me 

Comment: Please help me 

Answer (score 1):

you can use a trick if you put a element at least of the div  and the element with an id you can use this code

```
window.location = ('#id')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate it, use this code

`$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");`

Make sure you have [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/) on the page you're using this code on