# Button (back to bottom)

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do I change my function, to go to the bottom of the page instead to top ?

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
     $('.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
   } else {
     $('.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
   }
 });

 $('.back-to-top').click(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
  return false;
 })
```

thats the a tag

```
    <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Contact</a>
```

Comment: Give `scrollTop` a value which is the length or longer than the height of the page

Comment: What do you mean ? ( I never used jquery before) :(

Comment: `scrollTop: 0` takes you to the top of the page. Thinking logically, what would you expect to happen if you give it a larger value?

Comment: You are Jesus man thank you honestly !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Scroll To bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249353/jquery-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: YES <3 of course

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
  } else {
    $('.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
  }
});

$('.back-to-top').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
  }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
  return false;
})
```